# Strange lambda in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I can assign the following lambda to a variable.

```
val whatIsThat = {n: Int -> Int}
```

But what does it mean? Strangely enough, I can execute whatIsThat(2)

```
println(whatIsThat(2))
```

and the result is kotlin.jvm.internal.IntCompanionObject. Maybe it's a "secret feature"?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're printing out the companion object for `Int`, rather than an instance of `Int`. If you use `val whatIsThat = { n: Int -> Int.Companion }`, you'll get the same result. It seems like an unintended side effect of the way companion objects are handled in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Let's expand your declaration by explicitly stating its type:

```
val whatIsThat: (Int) -> Int.Companion = { n: Int -> Int}
```

I'm guessing you expected the type to be `(Int) -> Int`, right? But the syntax you used is not type declaration, it's the actual lambda body. Your lambda takes an `Int` and returns the `Int` singleton, whose type is `Int.Companion`.